# How can i set explicit array type without coping and pasting its values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an array:

```
const mediaFileKeys = ["mp3", "wave", "stems", "image"];
```

And i need it to have explicit value types.

So i copied and pasted its values:

```
const mediaFileKeys: ["mp3", "wave", "stems", "image"] = ["mp3", "wave", "stems", "image"];
```

Is there any way of doing that without having to copy the array values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `as const` assertion:

```
const mediaFileKeys = ["mp3", "wave", "stems", "image"] as const;
```